# Uploading image using JSP and Servlet in Oracle database

Tags: java, image, oracle, servlets, blob

As i mentioned in my title, i want to upload image into the database field. So, whatsoever I have done with my coding part. I'm sharing here. I don't think, there would be any problem with my code, since, i'm getting right output at the screen. But, the problem is, when i opened database, it showing some different output. I don't know, what is wrong in the database, when I try to execute `select * from PIC`. Then, `PIC` column shows some unexpected result. Don't know, whether my image is inserting into the table or not.

Thanks !!!

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <table width="400" align="center">
                <tr><td>UserName :</td><td><input type="file" name="userid" id="userid" /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="Submit" value="Upload" style="width: 100px; height:30px;"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
```

This my servlet page:

**upload.java**

```
package fileupload;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class upload extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        if (!isMultipart) {
            out.println("File Not Uploaded");
        } else {
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
            List items = null;
            try {
                items = upload.parseRequest(request);
                out.println("items: " + items);
            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileItem file = (FileItem) items.get(0);
            // out.print(file);
            Connection conn = null;
            String connstr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE";
            String uname = "epolicia";
            String password = "admin";
            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
            String sql = null;
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, uname, password);
                // FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(savedFile);
                sql = "INSERT INTO pic(pic) VALUES(?)";
                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                // st.setInt(1,1);
                st.setBinaryStream(1, file.getInputStream(), (int) file.getSize());
                int rs = st.executeUpdate();
                if (rs > 0) {
                    out.println("Query Executed Successfully++++++++++++++");
                }
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pages are successfully running without any exception. Help will be appreciated.

[image: screenshot of my database, after execution of above page]

Comment: at least, any one tell me, how to store image into oracle 10g xe. i'm stuck... plz, help me.!! It's urgent.

Comment: How do you know the data is not in there? Apparently there *are* rows in the table (or what should that screenshot show us?). The Java code looks fine to me with the only exception that you are missing a call to `commit()`

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name as you can see column PIC, it's showing [datatype], and when i'm trying to retrieve the image. then, it's showing null.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of interface or tool that is. Can you check with plain SQL (e.g. SQL*Plus) if the column is really empty?

Comment: yes, i did. when i executing the select query. it returns the above result. which i've uploaded.

Comment: I have no idea what that picture is supposed to show me. The column could be `NULL` or it could have data in it - I have no experience with that tool (whatever that is) and I have the suspicion that this tool is simply not showing you what you need to know. Please do use some other tool to verify the data. What is the result of `select length(pic) from pic` (or `select count(*) from pic where pic is null`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Thanks to everyone. I followed the steps which are mentioned in the website, the link, and I'm sharing the same links. So that, others will get the benefits of this.

[Upload photos into Oracle BLOB column from Java Servlet and listing photos](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/fileupload.aspx)

Since, image is being inserted in **`blob`** type, which `binary large object`, which can not displayed on that `sql*plus`. That's why was showing `[datatype]`.

Answer (score 1):

U can use data type Midblob  or blob in mysql. to store image.
midbolb data type stores large size morethan blob ..